# Woocommerce payment process

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, hook-woocommerce

The question regarding online payment, using the Woocommerce /
There is a goods page.
How on the same page to show Woocommerce checkout, so you can pay for the goods on the same page of the same product?
There is a plug-in from Woocommerce but expensive.
Can I use some hooks or somehow ajax to bring this page, a payment page?

This is what looks like on the product page, when you click on the type of payment, fields for the selected payment type should appear.
And when you click on MAKE A RESERVATION there should be a payment, everything should work Woocommerce in the same country, without transitions.
http://prntscr.com/gwvgtl

Comment: What kind of product do you sell? Do you want to complete the payment information without completing the information or with completing the information ?
In either case, this can be done